# Flutter compute function not compiling

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates

I have a repository class (check below) that calls APIs through the `HttpService` class. I'm receiving historical data that contains 1000s of data objects. To avoid the computation problem, I'm trying to implement the `compute()` function to move this computation out of the main thread, but Android Studio is giving a compilation error.

```
class WealthRepo {

    Future<Responser<PerformanceHistoryModel>> fetchPortfolioHistory(
    String stackId,
    String? duration,
    ) async {
    try {
      final resp = await _httpService.makePostRequest(<API_EP>, jsonEncode(<REQUEST_OBJ>));

      return Responser<PerformanceHistoryModel>(
        message: '',
        isSuccess: true,
        data: compute(parsePerformanceHistory, resp),
      );
    } catch (e, st) {
      return ErrorHandler.error<PerformanceHistoryModel>(
        e,
        stackTrace: st,
      );
    }
  }
}

/// Outside WealthRepo class
PerformanceHistoryModel parsePerformanceHistory(Map<String, dynamic> response) {
  return PerformanceHistoryModel.fromJson(response);
}
```

> lib/repositories/wealth_repo.dart:1431:23: Error: The argument type
> 'PerformanceHistoryModel Function(Map<String, dynamic>)' can't be
> assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr
> Function(dynamic)'.
>
> - 'PerformanceHistoryModel' is from 'package:aphrodite_v2/data/models/wealth/performance_history_model.dart'
>   ('lib/data/models/wealth/performance_history_model.dart').
> - 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
>   data: compute(parsePerformanceHistory, resp),
>   ^

**PS - `Responser` is a custom response class we created. Not sure how to resolve this issue.**

```
class Responser<T> {
  final String message;
  final bool isSuccess;
  T? data;

  Responser({
    required this.message,
    required this.isSuccess,
    this.data,
  });

  @override
  String toString() =>
      'Responser(message: $message, isSuccess: $isSuccess, data: $data)';
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You either need to `await` your `resp` before passing it into the `compute` function.

```dart
      return Responser<PerformanceHistoryModel>(
        message: '',
        isSuccess: true,                       \/\/     
        data: compute(parsePerformanceHistory, await resp),
      );
```

*Or* you need to update the signature on the function that `compute` uses so that it takes in a `FutureOr<Map<String, dynamic>>`.

```dart
  Future<PerformanceHistoryModel> parsePerformanceHistory(
      FutureOr<Map<String, dynamic>> _response) async {
    final response = await _response;
    return PerformanceHistoryModel.fromJson(response);
  }
```